# no localhost url prefix in wamp/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I have latest version of wamp and apache 2.4.9

I had three projects run fine for weeks.

Needed to start project #2 over again, used same project name, reinstalled wordpress with new database, no problems.

I can log in and work on it.

Nagging issue is why project #2 no longer resolves to localhost. After login to wordpress, url is http://project2.mysite/wp-admin/.

Projects 1 and 3 still resolve as http://localhost/project1(3).mysite/wp-admin/

Never changed hosts, httpd-vhosts or httpd-vhosts.conf files because all info is the same as original project #2

Any help appreciated
phil

Comment: no one has a suggestion?

Comment: This is probably because you installed project2 using the virtual hosts url `project2.mysite/` and project1&3 using `localhost/project1(3).mysite` WP remembers the url used when you run the install and makes use of that all over itself.